# How do you find the position of an automatically positioned element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a hidden game, where you can move one of the letters in a word around the screen. The sentence's position is relative, but the letter's position is absolute, so if it's position isn't set, it stays where it is in the sentence. But I can't seem to access that position with javascript.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", hidgame, false);

var vertpos; // = don't know what to put after the variables to get the top and left position.
var horipos; 

function hidgame(event) {
 if (event.keyCode == "38") {
  vertpos--
  document.getElementById("hidgame").style.top = vertpos + "px";
 }
        if (event.keyCode == "40") {
  vertpos++
  document.getElementById("hidgame").style.top = vertpos + "px";
 }
        if (event.keyCode == "37") {
  horipos--
  document.getElementById("hidgame").style.left = horipos + "px";
 }
        if (event.keyCode == "39") {
  horipos++
  document.getElementById("hidgame").style.left = horipos + "px";
 }
```

```css
#subtitle {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

#hidgame {
 position: absolute;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="subtitle">Hidden G<span id="hidgame">a</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;me</div> <!--The &nbsp; is only there to fill the space because the span is absolute-->
```

Comment: I guess you need this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine the position, use [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Also, consider storing your element as a variable instead of repeatedly looking it up.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", hidgame, false);

var letter  = document.getElementById("hidgame");
var vertpos = letter.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var horipos = letter.getBoundingClientRect().left;

function hidgame(event) {
  if      (event.keyCode == "38") vertpos--; //up
  else if (event.keyCode == "40") vertpos++; //down
  else if (event.keyCode == "37") horipos--; //left
  else if (event.keyCode == "39") horipos++; //right

  letter.style.top  = vertpos + "px";
  letter.style.left = horipos + "px";
}
```

```css
#subtitle {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#hidgame {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="subtitle">Hidden G<span id="hidgame">a</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;me</div>
<!--The &nbsp; is only there to fill the space because the span is absolute-->
```